# Segmentation fault in a quicksort implementation

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I wrote C++ code to implement quicksort. It compiles but crashes at runtime. I used codeblocks. When I use debugger, it says:

> 'segmentation fault' at line (45)"q=Partition(r,n);" in the definition of the partition function.

I searched for it and found some answers but none of them solved my problem here. Please tell me why this program doesn't run.

```
//Program for Quicksort

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Partition(int* p,int n);
void Qsort(int* p,int n);
void Swap(int* a,int* b);

int main()
{
    int n=0;                                              //array size
    cout<<"Enter array size\n";
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    cout<<"Now enter the array elements\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)                                
        cin>>a[i];                                        //read array
    int *p;
    p=a;
    Qsort(p,n);                                           //call Qsort, args:pointer to 
    cout<<"This is the sorted array:\n";                  //array, array size
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" "<<endl;                            //print sorted array
    return 0;
}
int Partition(int* p,int n)                               //the partition function
{
    int key=*(p+n-1);
    int i=-1,j=0;
    for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
    {
        if(*(p+j)<=key)
            {
                i++;
                Swap(p+i,p+j);
            }
    }

    *(p+i+1)=key;
    return i+1;
}
void Qsort(int* r,int n)
{
    int q=0;
    q=Partition(r,n);                          //The debugger points here and says 
    Qsort(r,q);                                //there is a segmentation fault
    Qsort(r+q+1,n-q-1);
}

void Swap(int* a,int* b)                       //To exchange two integer variables
{
    int t=0;
    t=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=t;
}
```

Comment: recursive function needs return point, otherwise stack overflow

Comment: int a[n]; ?? Which C++ version is this?

Comment: @MartinSchlott could be gcc extension

Comment: thank u all for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

billz's comment tells you exactly what's wrong, but let me try to put it into simpler words:

Your `Qsort` keeps calling itself over and over again, this cycle never stops until your machine runs out of resources. You forgot to include a return condition that would trigger when everything is done. In the case of sorting routines, this is usually when you call the sorting mechanism on a single element: There's nothing to sort then, so we may as well stop.

Try to include this condition in your program.

Comment: Thank u very much, u are absolutely right; and thanks again to stackoverflow.com for helping me get a reply so quickly